# I use last version react-native-maps, I add custom marker on map, using array, but when I remove marker, marker not removed from map

Tags: javascript, react-native, runtime-error, react-native-maps

**Summary**

I use last version react-native-maps, I add custom marker on map, using array, but when I remove marker, marker not removed from map...

**Video**

Just check video
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IpV-RX7RXMkqSSd1uZy2orfFnxFpty2N/view?usp=sharing

**Environment info**

```
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.67.4",
"react-native-maps": "^0.31.0",

Simulator Target Platform: iOS - 15.2.1 iPhone 11 (using Apple Maps)
Simulator Target Platform: iOS - 13.5.1 iPhone 6 (using Apple Maps)
```

**Steps to reproduce**

- Follow instruction steps for this package
- Add a marker by tapping anywhere in the MapView
- Tap 'clear markers' to set the marker array to empty

**Describe what you expected to happen:**

- Markers was remove

**Describe what actually happens:**

- Markers not removed

**Reproducible sample code**

```html
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Dimensions, Image, useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

const screen = Dimensions.get('window');
const ASPECT_RATIO = screen.width / screen.height;
const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.0029;
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = LATITUDE_DELTA * ASPECT_RATIO;

export default function MapSearch({ navigation, MapId, MapBaseID, TappedOnMapDetail }) {
  const dimensions = useWindowDimensions();
  const [pinCreate, setPinCreate] = useState(false);

  return (
    <MapView
      zoomControlEnabled={true}
      ref={mapRef}
      showsMyLocationButton={false}
      initialRegion={{
        latitude: 0,
        longitude: 0,
        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
      }}
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
    >
      {pinCreate == true && (
        <Image
          source={require('../../../../../assets/pin.png')}
          style={{
            width: 32,
            height: 32,
            resizeMode: 'contain',
            top: dimensions.width / 1.45,
            alignSelf: 'center',
          }}
        />
      )}

      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => setPinCreate(!pinCreate)}
        style={{
          borderRadius: 120,
          position: 'absolute',
          top: Dimensions.get('window').height / 1.9,
          right: 20,
          backgroundColor: 'red',
          height: 50,
          width: 50,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
        }}
      >
        <Image style={{ height: 25, width: 25, resizeMode: 'contain' }} source={require('../../../../../assets/wifi.png')} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </MapView>
  );
}
```